# Using Language Class in Controller (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, lang

First of all, I made research but couldn't find anything about it.

I'm sending flash data to users when they update or add something. My controller file's related part is like this;

```
function hizmet_ekle()
    {
        if($this->mhizmetler->hizmet_ekle())
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('ok', 'hizmet sisteme eklendi!');
            redirect('panel/hizmetler');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('hata', 'Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin!');
            redirect('panel/hizmetler');
        }
    }
```

And my view's related parts are like this;

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('ok')): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success fade in widget-inner">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('ok');?>
                </div>      
            <?php endif; if($this->session->flashdata('hata')): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in widget-inner">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('hata');?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; echo validation_errors('
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in widget-inner">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> ', '
                </div>'); ?>
```

My system has a few different languages, it means I have to send different notification messages(session flashdata's) for each language but I can't use `lang` key in my controller file. How can I handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

I have to use it like this;

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('ok', $this->lang->line("greek"));
```